# sql - Get count of matching rows from multiple joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the count of clicks and views belonging to individual rows in my "ads" table (which also belongs to a user).  I am also trying to order the result by the ads with the highest number of views.

My tables structure:

users:

```
id name
1  James
```

ads: belongs to users (FK: user_id)

```
id user_id
22 1
23 4
```

views: belongs to ads (FK: ad_id)

```
id ad_id
1  22
2  22
3  23
```

clicks: belongs to ads (FK: ad_id)

```
id ad_id
1  22
2  22
3  23
```

From the above tables, I want a result that contains data about all ads belonging to user with id = 1 and the click and view count for each ad

```
id user_id clicks_count views_count
22 1       2            2
```

This is what I have so far. With this SQL, I get the correct number of views and clicks for just one/first "ads" row but other matching rows are ignored.

```
SELECT ads.id, COUNT(DISTINCT views.id) AS view_count, COUNT(DISTINCT clicks.id) AS click_count   
FROM users
INNER JOIN ads ON ads.`user_id` = users.`id`
INNER JOIN views ON ads.id = views.`ad_id`
INNER JOIN clicks ON ads.id = clicks.`ad_id`
WHERE users.`id` = 1
GROUP BY views.`ad_id`
ORDER BY `view_count` DESC
```

Here is an sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c43c/1/0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query produces your desired result with the data you have specified:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef65.  (Your original SQL Fiddle had the wrong data for `clicks`.

Comment: It does but when I insert a new row in the "ads" table (with no clicks or views), it isn't returned along with the other ads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to not lose the ads which don't have clicks

```
SELECT ads.id, COUNT(DISTINCT views.id) AS view_count, COUNT(DISTINCT clicks.id) AS click_count   
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN ads ON ads.`user_id` = users.`id`
    LEFT JOIN views ON ads.id = views.`ad_id`
    LEFT JOIN clicks ON ads.id = clicks.`ad_id`
    WHERE users.`id` = 1
    GROUP BY ads.`id`
    ORDER BY `view_count` DESC
```

Comment: This worked when I changed "GROUP BY ads.`ad_id`" to "GROUP BY ads.`id`". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ads.id,ads.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT views.id) AS view_count, 
COUNT(DISTINCT clicks.id) AS click_count   
    FROM users
    inner JOIN ads ON ads.`user_id` = users.`id`
    LEFT JOIN views ON ads.id = views.`ad_id`
    LEFT JOIN clicks ON ads.id = clicks.`ad_id`
    WHERE users.`id` = 1
    GROUP BY views.`ad_id`
    ORDER BY `view_count` DESC
```

INNER is correct but you should use two left joins